# SQL Server Express database deployed shared hosting environment Login failed

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, database-connection, connection-string

I am using SQL Server Express to create a database, which I have deployed to a shared hosting environment.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Identity to login, however I cannot. I am now debugging locally with a connection to database on the server.

I receive the following error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

When restoring this database, the hosting company provide their own "username" and password that sits in the connection string.

Here is a sample connection string:

```
"Data Source=serveraddress;Initial Catalog=dbname;User Id=dbname_admin;Password=dbpassword;"
```

Here is my connection string in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="foorelease" 
         connectionString="Data Source=serveraddress;Initial Catalog=DB_A1FEEC_foodb;User Id=DB_A1FEEC_foodb_admin;Integrated Security=False;Trusted_Connection = True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I added the `Integrated Security=False;Trusted_Connection = True;` based on some digging around on the web, however I still receive same error.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing the login you're trying to use is SQL Server authentication, not Windows authentication, in which case, is your server set up for mixed authentication rather than just windows authentication?

Comment: The server is not set up to use windows authentication, i am using a shared hosting provider